# Bigquery - create surrogate keys on migrated data

Tags: google-bigquery, surrogate-key

We are doing a migration from AWS Redshift to GCP BigQuery.

Problem statement: 
We have a Redshift table that uses the IDENTITY column functionality to issue an internal EDW surrogate key (PK) for natural/business keys.  These natural keys are from at least 20 different source systems for customers.  We need a method to identify them in case natural keys are somehow duplicated (because we have so many source systems).  In BigQuery, the functionality of the Redshift IDENTITY column does not exist.  How can I replicate this in BQ?
We cant use GENERATE_UUID() because all our downstream clients have been using a BIGINT for the last 4 years.  All history is based on BIGINT and too much would need to change for a VARCHAR.
Does anyone have any ideas, recommendations or suggestions?

Some considerations I have made:
1. load the data into Spark and keep it in memory and use scala or python functions to issue the surrogate key.
2. use a nosql data store (but this does not seem likely as a use case).
Any ideas are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

In these cases, the idea is generally to identify an injective/bijective function, which can map to some unique space.

How about you try something like: `SELECT UNIX_MICROS(current_timestamp()) + x as identity` where `x` is a numeral that you can somehow manage (using `case` statements or `if` conditions) based on the business name or something?

You can also eliminate `x` from this formula if you intend to process things linearly in some order, like one business entity at a time.

Hope it helps.